# How do i correct this code to show google org. chart properly?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, google-visualization

This is webpage,where i want to show org. graph. dataArray variable store `[[{v:"John",f:"junior Employee"}, ,"Junior Employee"]]`
value. and i got data through ajax is `["[{v:"John",f:"Junior Employee"}, ,"Junior Employee"]"]`.

I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 3
```

Code:

```
  <html>
       <head>
            <title>Case Graphs</title>
            <script src="./js/my/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
            <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

        $("document").ready(function(){
        $("#getGraph").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
        url:"./DataPHP3.php",
        method:"POST",
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var length=data.length;

         google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

           var dataArray=[];

        for(var k=0;k<length;k++)
        {
        if(k==0)
        {
        dataArray+="["+data[k];
        }
        else
        {
        dataArray+=","+data[k];
        }
        }
        dataArray+="]";

        function drawChart() {


                console.log(dataArray);
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
                data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
                data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

                // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
                data.addRows(
             $.parseJSON(dataArray)
             //  [[{v:"John",f:"junior Employee"}, ,"Junior Employee"]]

                );

                // Create the chart.
                var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
                chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
              }

        },
        });


        });
        });
            </script>``
        </head>
        <body>
        <input type="button" id="getGraph" value="Show Graph">
             <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 400px"></div>
        </body>
        </html>

This is webpage,where i want to show org. graph. dataArray variable store [[{v:"John",f:"junior Employee"}, ,"Junior Employee"]]
value. and i got data through ajax is ["[{v:"John",f:"Junior Employee"}, ,"Junior Employee"]"].
I GOT THIS ERROR:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 3
```

Comment: use this method data.setCell() to write data in chart instead of copying  entire format !!!

Comment: formatting improved.

Answer (score 0):

need to wrap the object keys in quotes as well (`"v":`)...

```
[[{"v":"John", "f":"junior Employee"}, null, "Junior Employee"]]
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['orgchart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
  data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

  data.addRows(
    $.parseJSON('[[{"v":"John", "f":"junior Employee"}, null, "Junior Employee"]]')
  );

  var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    allowHtml: true
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: looks like you found a solution, but thought you might like to know why the error occurred...